# Flow text in 2 columns automatically with CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 divs and I need the text to flow in these 2 divs. The current jQuery collects the `<p>` tags and automatically splits the `<p>` in the 2 divs. What I need is when the first `<div>` is full, move the rest of text to another `<div>`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var size = $("#data > p").size();
  $(".Column1 > p").each(function (index) {
      if (index >= size / 2) {
          $(this).appendTo(".Column2");
      }
  });
});
```

Current script I did can be found on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPUmZ/197/).

Comment: What is the problem? Your explanation is totally confusing and unclear...

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess here, but is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/U69ZM/

Comment: @DavidAlsbright . i need that .. when the first div is full, move the rest of text to another div

Comment: But your jQuery was already doing that... Just the colouring was stopped due to CSS... :-)

Comment: @MohamedSamy So you need the 2 boxes to be 150px in height at all times?

Comment: wait a moment i need to rethink about the logic again

Comment: JQuery Columnizer does this: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/